# remove youtube branding logo with mediaelementjs

Tags: video, youtube, mediaelement.js

I'm using mediaelement.js library for videos to provide similar look and feel across browser s and devices. mediaelement.js has a youtube wrapper which allows us to use videos hosted on youtube. when I use this to display the videos, I see that youtube videos have a "youtube" logo on it. I tried appending modestbranding=1 to the url. when I add any parameter to the src url, the video does not play. Is there any solution to remove the youtube branding logo?

```
<video style="width:100%;height:100%" id="player1" preload="none">

<source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" >

</video>

<script>
    // declare object for video 

    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1',{ features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'] }); 
</script>
```